# custom from address in rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp

In my rails application I am trying to send mail using custom from address.

It works fine few times, but most of the time it doesn't work.
I am getting the following smtp error message

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (553 Sorry, your envelope sender is in my badmailfrom list.
):
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:687:in `check_response'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:660:in `getok'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:638:in `mailfrom'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:550:in `send0'
    C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:475:in `sendmail'
    /vendor/rails/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:638:in `perform_delivery_smtp'
```

Here is my sample code

In **mailer.rb**

```
  def mail_to_friend(recipient_mail, sender_mail, subjects, messages, host, port)
    @host = host
    @port = port

    recipients recipient_mail
    from       "#{sender_mail}"  #custom from address
    subject    "#{subjects}"
    sent_on    Time.now    
    body       :message_body => messages, :host => host, :port => port
    content_type "text/html"
  end
```

I am using Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.6. 
PS: I am not using google smtp server(using own smtp server)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just try to change the outgoing server from using your domain's smtp server to using gmail's.

Comment: It appears that the mail server itself is rejecting the sender.  WHat mail server is it?

Comment: Thanks for update. I want to send email using my site user email id.for ex: my user1 email id is user1[a]gmail.com and user2 is user2[a]yahoo.com ... I am giving share with friends option. That time I want to mail to his friends with his email ID. If I user my domain email id it work fine. When i user users I am getting that error. My user may have diff domain not only gmail, yahoo...

Answer (score 1):

The owner of the remote SMTP server banned you (or the guy you are impersonating), I guess because you were using their server to test weird stuff without asking for permission (or because what you are doing approximates what spammers do, and you triggered an automatic ban rule).